# How to tell if a class is supported by .Net Standard Library?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, .net-standard-1.5

My current specific situation is that I want to use [DataContractSerializer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer) in a library supporting .NETStandard1.3.  I am unable to reference it in the library.  The document gives me an impression that it is a part of .Net Standard Library.  Could you anyone offer a tip on how to determine if a class is supported by .Net Standard Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your one-stop shop for all .NET-based APIs 
[.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/)

- select .Net Standard
- select version
- Enter your search: DataContractSerializer

You find DataContractSerializer in  [.Net Standard 2.0  only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-2.0&term=System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer)

Comment: This is neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The first version supporting that is .NET Standard 2.0.

You can search at [apisof](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer) to find out what frameworks contain an API.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the .NET Core docs.

In the .NET Support chart:

[image]

you can see that NetStandard1.3 does not support .NET Core.  You'd have to move up to 2.0

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elucidation.  How do you tell it is the .NET core docs. Why doesn't .Net Standard 1.6 support it?  According to your chart, netstandard 1.6 supports .NET Core 1.0. Probably I do not fully understand the chart.

Comment: sorry - you're right, if you target netstandard1.6 you can use .net core 1.0

Comment: This answer has the relationship inverted -- .NET Core supports .NET Standard, not the other way around. So .NET Core can have additional features that are not in .NET Standard.

Comment: Now, I am getting "error : Your project is not referencing the ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" framework. Add a reference to ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore."  I get this for a brand new libary targeting netstandard 1.6