# How to find out since which .NET Standard version a given type or member is supported?

Tags: .net, .net-standard

For previous versions of the .NET Framework, the documentation on MSDN would allow you to find out which versions of the framework support a given type or member. For instance, if I open the documentation (any version, e.g. the most recent one) of [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx), there is a version info section:

[image: Version Info section on System.Linq.Expressions.Expression from MSDN]

It tells me at a glance since which version of the .NET Framework, and also since which versions in other related frameworks such as Windows Phone or Silverlight the type has been available.

Alternatively, for the minimum .NET Framework version, I don't even have to scroll down: Opening the list of links to other documentation versions right in the page header is sufficient to see which Framework version is the earliest:

[image: Page header on System.Linq.Expressions.Expression from MSDN]

Now, I have learned from questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683909/how-to-tell-if-a-class-is-supported-by-net-standard-library) that documentation for .NET Standard can be found on the [.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/).

There, I can apparently search all documentation versions for `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`, which will successfully send me to the documentation on this class. Somehow, documentation is set to .NET 4.7 by default (latest framework version, maybe?).

**But how can I see here in which versions the class is supported?**

It's *not* the list of other documentation versions:

[image: Page header on System.Linq.Expressions.Expression from .NET API Browser]

While nicely structured, this popup displays *all* frameworks for which any documentation is available. If you pick a framework or framework version that does not support the currently selected namespace (try, for instance, `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo` with .NET Standard 1.0), type, or member, you are automatically redirected to the documentation from the most recent framework version that does. Obviously, using this hit-and-miss approach to get a systematic overview of where a given namespace, type, or member is available is very tedious.

Comment: Vote for this improvement: https://msdocs.uservoice.com/forums/364242-site-feedback/suggestions/18855367-when-browsing-net-standard-show-the-minimum-vers

Comment: Also https://msdocs.uservoice.com/forums/364242-site-feedback/suggestions/18937474-bring-back-the-version-information-section-in-do

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/docs/versions If you download the files and then do a text search, you can find it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this issue was fixed in the meantime: All type/member-related articles on learn.microsoft.com now contain an *Applies to* section that contains all the necessary information:

[image: Applies to section from System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but you can try http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

If you search for a type there, the site will show you which .NET Standard package the type is in, and also what versions of .NET Standard support that type.

Comment: That is weird: When I use it to search for `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo`, it will display 47 results. All of them are marked with `netstandard1.3` and `netstandard1.4`. When I check that type in .NET API Browser, it seems that it is only available in .NET Standard 2.0, though.

Comment: I can tell you that the type is definitely supported in 1.3, once you install the indicated `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters` package, so I'm not sure what's going on with the API Browser page.

Comment: "so I'm not sure what's going on with the API Browser page" - maybe, but are you sure about what's going on with the site you pointed to? As I pointed out, it indicates `netstandard1.3` and `netstandard1.4`. What about `netstandard1.5` - my understanding was that new .NET Standard versions are supersets of previous versions. Or is that only the case for the switch from 1.6 to 2.0?

Comment: Yes, newer versions are supersets of previous versions. The packagsearch site is not an official MS site; it was developed by a third party and apparently hasn't been updated recently, although it's widely recommended.